# Little bug at closing flutter app. Drawer menu is the last thing showed

Tags: android, flutter, mobile, screen, navigator

I made an app in flutter, and to remove the screens from the Flutter stack, i used WillPopScope() inside the MyList stateful class:

```
 class MyList extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyList({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyLis> createState() => _MyList();
}

class _MyList extends State<MyList> {
  RefreshController refreshController =
      RefreshController(initialRefresh: false);
  List<Widget> dispositivos = <Widget>[];
  bool valor = false;


  @override
  void initState() {/*   */}

  DateTime timeBackPressed = DateTime.now();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async {
        print('Backbutton pressed'); 

        final difference = DateTime.now().difference(timeBackPressed);
        final avisoSaida = difference >= const Duration(seconds: 2);

        if (avisoSaida) {
          const msg = 'Press again to come back to the login page.';
          Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: msg, fontSize: 18);

          return false;
        } else {
          Fluttertoast.cancel();
          accountService.logout();
          return true;
          //exit(0);
        }
      },

    child: Scaffold(
          ...
        ),
        drawer: const NavigationBarWidget(),
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: colorTheme.kLightSecundaryColor,
          title: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              const Text(
                'My List',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 14,
                ),
              ),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: [
                  Padding(
                    padding:
                        EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: size.width * 0.02),
                    child: InkWell(
                      onTap: () {
                        Navigator.push(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (context) =>
                                    const Add()));
                      },
                      child: Icon(
                        Icons.add,
                        color: Colors.white,
                        size: size.width * 0.05,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

When i press the backbutton or click on exit button inside the drawer menu, the app goes
to the login screen, which is the first screen when the user opens the app. What i wanna do it is close the app in the same way that most flutter apps close.
Now, when i press the backbutton for example, the app goes to the login page, but when i press the backbutton again, the last screen which is showed is the
NavigationBarWidget(), and following the app is closed. This an excerpt of the NavigationBarWidget():

```
class NavigationBarWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  
  const NavigationBarWidget({
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Drawer(
        child: Material(
          children: <Widget>[
            ListTile(
              contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(25, 20, 5, 15),
              style: ListTileStyle.drawer,
              hoverColor: Colors.white10,
              minLeadingWidth: 5,
              title: Image.asset(
                'assets/img/logo_white.png',
                width: 50,
                height: 50,
                alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
              ),
              onTap: () {
                ...
              },
            ),
            Container(
              height: 1,
              margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(18, 0, 20, 10),
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white30),
            ),
            buildMenuItem(
                context: context,
                text: 'My List',
                icon: Icons.devices_other_outlined,
                // page: const MeusDispositivos()),
                page: '/meus_dispositivos'),
            buildMenuItem(
                context: context,
                text: 'Exit',
                icon: Icons.logout,
                // page: const LoginScreen(),
                page: '/login',
                callback: () {
                  accountService.logout();
                }),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget buildMenuItem({
    required String text,
    void Function()? callback,
  }) {
    const color = Colors.white;
    const hoverColor = Colors.white10;

    // serverConnection.context = context;

    return ListTile(
      leading: Icon(
        icon,
        color: color,
        size: 16,
      ),
      ...
      hoverColor: hoverColor,
      onTap: () {
        if (callback != null) {
          callback();
        }
        Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(page, (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
      },
    );
  }
}
```

I used Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(page, (Route route) => false) and it didn't work. All i really want is close the login page without showing Drawer Menu as the last 'screen.
Someone knows how to fix this?